# How to get distinct rows in hive if a column is blank

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am using hive to generate my output and trying to get distinct rows in my output.

I am using `select distinct c1,c2,c3,c4 from table`.

I have the below rows in the table as example

```
C1       C2    C3    C4

Value1 value2      value4

Value1 value2      value4
```

here, the column C3 is a blank and the expected output is just a single column among those. But even after using the distinct keyword, I am not able to get a single row as output. I am seeing both the records in the output.

Please help me if anyone have faced this issue before and possible solution if you have one.

Comment: check to see if `C3` is `NULL` or `` just empty string, Because your query has no error and must return one record.

Comment: Thanks wahjee, I did a COALESE for all the columns and hence I wasn't able to figure it out. But when the distinct operation is performed, it was NULL as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of DISTINCT is : It specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

Let's say, you are using distinct on multiple columns,It will consider each column unique value.

Example:

```
hive> SELECT col1, col2 FROM t1
    1 3
    1 3
    1 4
    2 5
hive> SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM t1
    1 3
    1 4
    2 5
hive> SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM t1
    1
    2
```

In your case, there may be possibiity that any column can have  different values, and that's why you are getting 2 rows as output.

Please refer the [HIVE DISTINCT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-ALLandDISTINCTClauses)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the case ,which is hard to debug. Column C3 might contain value which is neither null even nor ''. you should consider `casting` column C3.

```
select distinct col1,cast(col2 as string),col3 from test_nulls;
```